# how to validate Facebook username and password from our app in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, ios7, social-networking

I need a suggestion .I have two Uitextfield and one submit button.
when i enter Facebook username and password and click submit button it will validate from client side.
whether i need to add Facebook api or anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to just login to your app using Facebook no need to add api.
That can be done from server side.

But if you want to use any functionality of Facebook you will require the Facebook logged in user's access_token in response from server and also will require to add the Facebook framework in your app

Comment: No i need validate the Facebook id from client side

Comment: So you mean you need to fetch Facebook id from app first then validate it from client side